# Wire color for group instances in Matcap Solid View in User Preferences

Tags: 3d-view, instances, theme, matcaps

[image]

I want to capture Matcap shading and wires for workflow images.
However, the wire color of the group instance is white in the Matcap view.
I want black like any other object.
I looked at all of the 3D view color options in the Blender User Preference theme, but I couldt change the white wire in the Matcap view.

Comment: The best I can think of is using [wireframe rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+wireframe) methods and compositing them, in compositing you can adjust the colour to suit.

Comment: Blender has many color options, but I think I've met an exception.
I wanted to have a single click of the capture button, but I think I need to perform the compositing as you say.